# Mongodb Force read-only via connection string

Tags: mongodb, connection-string, readonly

Is there a way to force the connection to mongodb to be read-only via connection string? I don't want to have to create a read-only user in every environment to run some tests that I want to make sure don't change the database

Comment: No, privileges are manged by **user**, not by connection string. However, typically the connection string also contains the user name, so what is your problem? Creating a user is a single command - and dropping the user after your test is no problem either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because connection string is interpreted by the client. Access control is enforced by the server.

Comment: I feel like this begs the question, why can't the client ask the server to ignore writes, but since it's the reality here you go

Comment: The client can not send the writes in the first place. Why would someone send writes AND ask to ignore them.